# Intel Skeletal Hand Tracking Library with Kinect

Tags: kinect, tracking, intel

I've found this -> http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/the-intel-skeletal-hand-tracking-library-experimental-release

I think is a good one...the problem is that i don't want to buy the "Creative Interactive Gesture Camera"...instead i want to use my Kinect.
It's not so easy and i need your help. I started with the Init() 
this one is the original function :

```
inline bool Tracker::Init()
{
    if(PXCSession_Create(session.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !session.IsValid()) return false;

    for(int i=0; ; ++i) // For valid capture contexts
    { 
        PXCSession::ImplDesc desc, filter = { PXCSession::IMPL_GROUP_SENSOR, PXCSession::IMPL_SUBGROUP_VIDEO_CAPTURE };
        if(session->QueryImpl(&filter, i, &desc) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
        if(session->CreateImpl(&desc, PXCCapture::CUID, (void**)capture.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !capture.IsValid()) continue;

        for(int j=0; ; ++j) // For valid devices
        { 
            PXCCapture::DeviceInfo dinfo;
            if(capture->QueryDevice(j, &dinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
            if(capture->CreateDevice(j, device.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !device.IsValid()) continue;

            for(int k=0; ; ++k) // For valid video streams
            { 
                PXCCapture::Device::StreamInfo sinfo; 
                if(device->QueryStream(k, &sinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
                if(sinfo.cuid != PXCCapture::VideoStream::CUID || device->CreateStream(k, PXCCapture::VideoStream::CUID, (void**)stream.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !device.IsValid()) continue;

                for (int m=0; ; ++m) // For depth buffer profiles of at least 60 FPS
                { 
                    PXCCapture::VideoStream::ProfileInfo pinfo;
                    if(stream->QueryProfile(m, &pinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
                    if(pinfo.imageInfo.format != PXCImage::IMAGE_TYPE_DEPTH || pinfo.frameRateMin.numerator / pinfo.frameRateMin.denominator < 60 || stream->SetProfile(&pinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) continue;

                    // If we can read at least one frame
                    stream->ReadStreamAsync(image.ReleaseRef(), sp.ReleaseRef());
                    if(sp && sp->Synchronize() >= PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR)
                    {
                        // Obtain useful properties and reserve room for local copies of depth and color images
                        dimx = pinfo.imageInfo.width; dimy = pinfo.imageInfo.height;
                        PXCPointF32 flen; device->QueryPropertyAsPoint(PXCCapture::Device::PROPERTY_DEPTH_FOCAL_LENGTH, &flen);
                        fovx = atan(dimx / (flen.x*2))*2; fovy = atan(dimy / (flen.y*2))*2;
                        color = new unsigned char[dimx*dimy*3];
                        depth = new unsigned short[dimx*dimy];

                        // Initialize tracking library
                        tracker = hsklCreateTracker(HSKL_COORDS_X_RIGHT_Y_DOWN_Z_FWD, HSKL_API_VERSION);
                        hsklSetSensorProperties(tracker, HSKL_SENSOR_CREATIVE, dimx, dimy, fovx, fovy);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                stream.ReleaseRef();
            }
            device.ReleaseRef();
        }
        capture.ReleaseRef();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

this one is mine :

```
inline bool Tracker::Init()
{
    if(PXCSession_Create(session.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !session.IsValid()) return false;

    for(int i=0; ; ++i) // For valid capture contexts
    { 
        PXCSession::ImplDesc desc, filter = { PXCSession::IMPL_GROUP_SENSOR, PXCSession::IMPL_SUBGROUP_VIDEO_CAPTURE };
        if(session->QueryImpl(&filter, i, &desc) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
        if(session->CreateImpl(&desc, PXCCapture::CUID, (void**)capture.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !capture.IsValid()) continue;

        for(int j=0; ; ++j) // For valid devices
        { 
            PXCCapture::DeviceInfo dinfo;
            if(capture->QueryDevice(j, &dinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
            if(capture->CreateDevice(j, device.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !device.IsValid()) continue;

            for(int k=0; ; ++k) // For valid video streams
            { 
                PXCCapture::Device::StreamInfo sinfo; 
                if(device->QueryStream(k, &sinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
                if(sinfo.cuid != PXCCapture::VideoStream::CUID || device->CreateStream(k, PXCCapture::VideoStream::CUID, (void**)stream.ReleaseRef()) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR || !device.IsValid()) continue;

                for (int m=0; ; ++m) // For depth buffer profiles of at least 60 FPS
                { 
                    PXCCapture::VideoStream::ProfileInfo pinfo;
                    //if(stream->QueryProfile(m, &pinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) break;
                    //if(pinfo.imageInfo.format != PXCImage::IMAGE_TYPE_DEPTH || pinfo.frameRateMin.numerator / pinfo.frameRateMin.denominator < 60 || stream->SetProfile(&pinfo) < PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR) continue;


                    //Sleep(1000);
                    dimx=(int)K.m_colorWidth;
                    dimy=(int)K.m_colorHeight;
                    fovx=0.99;
                    fovy=0.75;


                    // If we can read at least one frame
                    stream->ReadStreamAsync(image.ReleaseRef(), sp.ReleaseRef());
                    if((sp && sp->Synchronize() >= PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR)||true)
                    {
                        // Obtain useful properties and reserve room for local copies of depth and color images
                        //dimx = pinfo.imageInfo.width; dimy = pinfo.imageInfo.height;
                        //PXCPointF32 flen; device->QueryPropertyAsPoint(PXCCapture::Device::PROPERTY_DEPTH_FOCAL_LENGTH, &flen);

                        //fovx = atan(dimx / (flen.x*2))*2; fovy = atan(dimy / (flen.y*2))*2;
                        color = new unsigned char[dimx*dimy*3];
                        depth = new unsigned short[dimx*dimy];

                        // Initialize tracking library
                        tracker = hsklCreateTracker(HSKL_COORDS_X_RIGHT_Y_DOWN_Z_FWD, HSKL_API_VERSION);
                        hsklSetSensorProperties(tracker, HSKL_SENSOR_IDEAL, dimx, dimy, fovx, fovy);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                stream.ReleaseRef();
            }
            device.ReleaseRef();
        }
        capture.ReleaseRef();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

And this is the original update class :

```
inline void Tracker::Update() 
{ 
    if(sp && sp->Synchronize() >= PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR)
    {
        PXCImage::ImageData depthData; image->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, &depthData);
        memcpy_s(depth, sizeof(unsigned short)*dimx*dimy, depthData.planes[0], sizeof(unsigned short)*dimx*dimy);
        const unsigned short * conf = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(depthData.planes[1]);
        for(int i=0; i<dimx*dimy; ++i) color[3*i+2] = color[3*i+1] = color[3*i] = conf[i]>>2; // Can we just use IR here?
        hsklTrackOneFrame(tracker, depth, conf); // Pass data to tracking library
        image->ReleaseAccess(&depthData);   
    }

    stream->ReadStreamAsync(image.ReleaseRef(), sp.ReleaseRef());
}
```

and mine :

```
inline void Tracker::Update() 
{ 
    if((sp && sp->Synchronize() >= PXC_STATUS_NO_ERROR)||true)
    {
        Mat matd(dimy,dimx,CV_16UC1);
        Mat matir(dimy,dimx,CV_16UC1);
        K.getDepth(&matd);
        matir = K.getIR();

        double min,max;
        cv::minMaxLoc(matir,&min,&max);
        Mat exit(dimy,dimx,CV_8UC1);
        matir.convertTo(exit,CV_8U,pow(2.0,8.0)/max);

        memcpy_s(depth,sizeof(unsigned short)*dimx*dimy,(unsigned short*)(matd.ptr()),sizeof(unsigned short)*dimx*dimy);
        const unsigned short * conf = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(matir.ptr());
        //PXCImage::ImageData depthData; image->AcquireAccess(PXCImage::ACCESS_READ, &depthData);
        //memcpy_s(depth, sizeof(unsigned short)*dimx*dimy, depthData.planes[0], sizeof(unsigned short)*dimx*dimy);
        //const unsigned short * conf = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned short *>(depthData.planes[1]);
    // Can we just use IR here?
        for(int i=0; i<dimx*dimy; ++i) {
            color[3*i+2] = color[3*i+1] = color[3*i] = (exit.at<unsigned char>(i)) ;


        }
        hsklTrackOneFrame(tracker, depth, conf); // Pass data to tracking library
        //image->ReleaseAccess(&depthData); 
    }

    stream->ReadStreamAsync(image.ReleaseRef(), sp.ReleaseRef());
}
```

If i try to run the program there are no errors...but it doesn't track my hand...So any suggestions ?? or is there somebody who is interested and want to share the project with me ?
thanks